# WCF web.config is getting overwritten after every compilation?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, refresh, web-config, overwrite

I have a Silverlight application calling a WCF service. SimplehttpBinding stuff.

1. Every I make changes to silverlight xaml code, the web.config gets refrshed also.
2. Even if make any changes to web.cofig file, they get overwritten too.

Its as if, some other process is writing these files. Why is that happening? How can I make sure that it does not get overwritten after every compile?

Answer (score 0):

Check your solution if you have another web.config in a different directory with property `Copy to output directory` set to `Copy Always`.

I had a similar problem before I realized I had that property set.